# What's the difference between tensorflow dynamic_rnn and rnn?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

There are several classes in `tf.nn` that relate to RNNs. In the examples I find on the web, `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` and `tf.nn.rnn` seem to be used interchangeably or at least I cannot seem to figure out why one is used in place of the other. What is the difference?

Comment: See also this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/q/42497216/3924118, where the author asks about the equivalent function of `tf.nn.rnn` for more recent versions of TensorFlow, which seems to be `tf.nn.static_rnn`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From [RNNs in Tensorflow, a Practical Guide and Undocumented Features](http://www.wildml.com/2016/08/rnns-in-tensorflow-a-practical-guide-and-undocumented-features/) by Denny Britz, published in August 21, 2016.

> `tf.nn.rnn` creates an unrolled graph for a fixed RNN length. That
>   means, if you call `tf.nn.rnn` with inputs having 200 time steps you are
>   creating a static graph with 200 RNN steps. First, graph creation is
>   slow. Second, you’re unable to pass in longer sequences (> 200) than
>   you’ve originally specified.
>
> `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` solves this. It uses a `tf.While` loop to dynamically
>   construct the graph when it is executed. That means graph creation is
>   faster and you can feed batches of variable size.

Comment: Why would one still use static RNN if the dynamic RNN provides all the advantages with practically no downsides?

Comment: Did you mean to say to "feed different sequence length"? As far as I know one can easily feed different batches in any graph, just declare proper placeholders.

Answer (score 2):

They are nearly the same, but there is a little difference in the structure of input and output. From documentation:

> `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`
>
> This function is functionally identical to the function `rnn` above, but >performs fully dynamic unrolling of inputs.
>
> Unlike `rnn`, the input inputs is not a Python list of Tensors, one for
>   each frame. Instead, inputs may be a single Tensor where the maximum
>   time is either the first or second dimension (see the parameter
>   `time_major`). Alternatively, it may be a (possibly nested) tuple of
>   Tensors, each of them having matching batch and time dimensions. The
>   corresponding output is either a single Tensor having the same number
>   of time steps and batch size, or a (possibly nested) tuple of such
>   tensors, matching the nested structure of `cell.output_size`.

For more details, explore [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py#L677).