# How to create end execute a basic LSTM network in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I want to create a basic LSTM network that accept sequences of 5 dimensional vectors (for example as a N x 5 arrays) and returns the corresponding sequences of 4 dimensional hidden- and cell-vectors (N x 4 arrays), where N is the number of time steps.

How can I do it TensorFlow?

**ADDED**

So, far I got the following code working:

```
num_units = 4
lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units = num_units)

timesteps = 18
num_input = 5
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, timesteps, num_input])
x = tf.unstack(X, timesteps, 1)
outputs, states = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm, x, dtype=tf.float32)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

x_val = np.random.normal(size = (12,18,5))
res = sess.run(outputs, feed_dict = {X:x_val})
sess.close()
```

However, there are many open questions:

1. Why number of time steps is preset? Shouldn't LSTM be able to accept sequences of arbitrary length?
2. Why do we split data by time-steps (using unstack)?
3. How to interpret the "outputs" and "states"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why number of time steps is preset? Shouldn't LSTM be able to accept
>   sequences of arbitrary length?

If you want to accept sequences of arbitrary length, I recommend using `dynamic_rnn`.You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734146/whats-the-difference-between-tensorflow-dynamic-rnn-and-rnn) to understand the difference between them.

For example:

```
num_units = 4
lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units = num_units)

num_input = 5
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, None, num_input])
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm, X, dtype=tf.float32)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

x_val = np.random.normal(size = (12,18,5))
res = sess.run(outputs, feed_dict = {X:x_val})

x_val = np.random.normal(size = (12,16,5))
res = sess.run(outputs, feed_dict = {X:x_val})
sess.close()
```

`dynamic_rnn` require same length in one batch , but you can specify every length using the `sequence_length` parameter after you pad batch data when you need arbitrary length in one batch.

> We do we split data by time-steps (using unstack)?

Just `static_rnn` needs to split data with `unstack`,this depending on their different input requirements. The input shape of `static_rnn` is `[timesteps,batch_size, features]`, which is a list of 2D tensors of shape `[batch_size, features]`. But the input shape of `dynamic_rnn` is either `[timesteps,batch_size, features]` or `[batch_size,timesteps, features]` depending on `time_major` is True or False.

> How to interpret the "outputs" and "states"?

The shape of `states` is `[2,batch_size,num_units ]` in LSTMCell, one `[batch_size, num_units ]` represents **C** and the other `[batch_size, num_units ]` represents **h**. You can see pictures below.

[image]

[image]

In the same way, You will get the shape of `states` is `[batch_size, num_units ]` in GRUCell.

`outputs` represents the output of each time step, so by default(time_major=False) its shape is `[batch_size, timesteps, num_units]`. And You can easily conclude that
`state[1, batch_size, : ] == outputs[ batch_size, -1, : ]`.