# How should the input shape of Keras LSTM layer looks like

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I've been reading for a while about training `LSTM` models using `tf.keras`, where i did use the same framework for regression problems using simple `feedforward NN` architectures and i highly understand how should i prepare the input data for such models,  however when it comes for training `LSTM`, i feel so confused about the shape of the input.

There is a lot to take care about: `time steps`, `number of samples`, `batch size`, `number of units`, etc. In addition to many parameters for the `LSTM` `keras` layer that aren't clear for me yet as what is shown in the below example:

```
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(units=3, batch_input_shape=(8,2,10), return_sequence=True, stateful= True))
```

So I have the following forex data structure where i don't know how to reshape it properly for an LSTM model.

```
open | close | high | low | volume | i1 | i2 | i3 | ... | i30 | nextClose
```

These features represents the open/close/high/low prices of a certain currency pair, in addition to the volume and 30 different indicators' values from i1 -> i30, all of these features corresponds to one minuet tick. Besides the nextClose feature represents the next minuet tick close price value that I'm trying hopefully to predict.

**Q1:** Could anyone please explain the general concept of how the data should be shaped for input, and what are all of these required parameters (time step, batch size...)?

**Q2:** Where I think a simple example could be great, How should my data structure above be reshaped to look like a valid input for LSTM?

Comment: Maybe you need [Understanding Keras LSTMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714959/understanding-keras-lstms).

Comment: @giser_yugang thanks for response i will check it

Comment: @giser_yugang please check my update

Comment: There's no big problem. The input shape of LSTM have two formats `[timesteps,batch_size, features]` or `[batch_size,timesteps, features]` in keras. You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54764500/how-to-create-end-execute-a-basic-lstm-network-in-tensorflow/54768066#54768066.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search i found this excellent summary for `keras LSTM` in a diagram, that was so helpful. check it in the [Keras_LSTM_Diagram](https://github.com/MohammadFneish7/Keras_LSTM_Diagram) git repository.